Opposite results between `bool(x)` and `x.__bool__()` after patching
In this simple little test case, I monkey patch the __bool__ method of an instance, but am surprised to see that calling bool(x) and x.__bool__() give opposite results afterwards. What is the explanation for this behavior? Is it a bug or a feature of the language? Thanks.
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define class #
class Person:
    def __bool__(self):
        return False

# Create instance #
bob = Person()

# Call test methods #
print("- Before monkey patching -")
print("Using __bool__(): ", bob.__bool__()) # False
print("Using bool(): ", bool(bob)) # False

# Patch #
def always_true(x): return True
bob.__bool__ = always_true.__get__(bob, bob.__class__)

# Call test methods #
print("- After monkey patching -")
print("Using __bool__(): ", bob.__bool__()) # True
print("Using bool(): ", bool(bob)) # False

Will print this with python 3.12:
- Before monkey patching -
Using __bool__():  False
Using bool():  False
- After monkey patching -
Using __bool__():  True
Using bool():  False

The same result is obtained when going the from types import MethodType route.

Methods are looked up on the class: bool(bob) is basically Person.__bool__(bob), which is still False, not bob.__bool__().
